# Google Sheets: autofill by multiple range of column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

im trying to make this autofill in one columm, if some cell on my account data is containing number for transaction of "Deposit and "Withdrawal" but i dont know how.
can someone please help?

[image]

i haven't try anything just yet, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data following formula should work-

```
=BYROW(E5:H11,LAMBDA(r,IF(SUM(r)>0,"Deposite","Withdrawal")))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you may be right regarding what the OP is asking, EXCEPT, you missed the part about the dynamic part -- ("auto fill itself"). I'm sure you know how to do this and I gave you a  nice answer

Answer (score 0):

### Updated

Based on other answer, I think this is what you're looking for. Only difference between answers is this one will spill as you specified.

This one will work and can be updated for any number of columns by only changing the byrow parameter

```
=let(sRng,byrow(e5:H,LAMBDA(eRow,sum(eRow))),filter(if(sRng>0,"Deposit","Withdrawal"),sRng<>0))
```

This one is longer, and would need additional if statements for more columns, but I believe it would perform significantly faster over major datasets.

```
=let(zValues,filter(E5:H,
if(isnumber(F5:F),true,if(isnumber(G5:G),true,if(isnumber(H5:H),true,isnumber(E5:E))))),
byrow(zValues,LAMBDA(eRow,if(sum(eRow)>0,"Deposit","Withdrawal"))))
```

### Original Answer

It's not clear what your output should be but assuming you have data as [your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxhZc.png) indicates, then this formula should give you Withdrawals:

```
=let(zColumn,"Withdrawal",zRange,D:G,zCleanList,
tocol(filter(zRange,CHOOSECOLS(zRange,1)=zColumn),1),
VSTACK(zColumn,filter(zCleanList,isnumber(zcleanlist))))
```

Swap in `Deposit` for the second parameter and you should get a result something like this:

[image]

Comment: sorry this is not what i mean, its more like word version of "time stamp", so whenever the transaction certain amount is insert in the one of these account column below, the Deposit or Withdraw "stamp" will appear by itself below "transaction type" column.
like non-minus amount is Deposit, and minus amount is Withdrawal, hope this can enlighten.

Comment: why not take the time and demonstrate what sort of data you have, and what you're expecting the final result to be using a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: here you go @pgSystemTester
https://imgur.com/a/64tv2e7

=if(B1>0,"Deposit",IF(B1<0,"Withdrawal","")
i need to make the second parameter "B1" is not only 1 cell, 
but to the entire row cell like B2 B3 B4 so on

Comment: its more like this
IF cell B1 to D1 contain ">0", then cell A1 will show "Deposit"
or
IF cell B1 to D1 contain "<0", then cell A1 will show "Withdraw"